# PHP selecting from db to display username?

Tags: php

So I'm trying to select the username from the users table BASED ON if they are in a gang.

Vars used.:

```
$member_gang = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT level,gangid,rating FROM user_stats WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "'"));
$gang_info = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gangs WHERE id = '".$member_gang['gangid']."'"));
```

And here's when I want to display it.

```
$getmembers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_stats WHERE gangid = '" . $gang_info['gangid'] . "'"));

$displaymembers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $getmembers['id'] . "'"));

echo 'One Member of this gang is: <b>'.$displaymembers['username'].' </b>:)';
```

(I do have db connection etc..) It's not echoing the username?!

EDIT: I am not that good at PHP, i don't understand prepared statements?

Comment: Any MySQL errors? Have you checked the intermediate results?

Comment: Why are you querying `id` like it was a atring. Is your `id` and `gangid` fields are strings?

Comment: echo $getmembers['id']; what do you get?

Comment: Using prepared statements would improve your code, I think

Comment: I get nothing when i echo $getmembers['id'];  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$gang_info['id']
```

not

```
$gang_info['gangid']
```

because you wrote above

```
"SELECT * FROM gangs WHERE id...."
```

and not

```
"SELECT * FROM gangs WHERE gangid..."
```

?

And why did you set the Ids in ' '? Are they strings? When not, change them to integer, thats a better solution for primary keys.

Comment: The row "gangid" is inside user_stats

Comment: Yeah, but have you testet the change to $gang_info['id']? What shows a var_dump() of member_gang and gang_info and the other 2 arrays?

Comment: Thats what i wrote, you must change id to: $getmembers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_stats WHERE gangid = '" . $gang_info['id'] . "'")); and $displaymembers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $getmembers['gangid'] . "'")); Or change your table structure, so that you have the same names for the ids in every tabel, not one times gangid and some times id (what is a worse name for a primary key)

Comment: but wait, i want to fetch more than 1 user that is in the same gangid from the user_stats table.. ;3